# manually set Jenkins Build Number?

Tags: jenkins

is it possible to select the Jenkins Build Number? For example, I'm now making 14, but it had an error. Without detailing the why, I'd like to be able to delete #14, and remake a new #14, is it possible?

I know it goes against the logic, but in a particular case we have, it would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You may use [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin) plugin to set the next build number. Although, do note that you really shouldn't be doing this anyway.</s>

It seems that Jenkins *requires* that the next build number be greater than the last. AFAICT, there's no way to do what you request.

Comment: I just tried it more, actually it doesn't let you go back to a previous unuse number. If for example I started at 8, then I cannot go back before 8 after thats.